# How to set the default encoding to Unicode?

Tags: firefox, encoding, unicode, iceweasel

How do I set the *default* encoding in Firefox/Iceweasel to Unicode (instead of Western)?

I'm particularly interested in the default encoding for *.txt files.  Firefox/Iceweasel seems to *always* choose Western as the encoding for such files.  I know that I can change the encoding for a particular page through View > Character Encoding, but it gets tiresome after a while.

Comment: Are you using a localized version of Firefox/Iceweasel, rather than 'English (US)'?

Comment: @user3169: I don't recall performing any special configuration to that effect.  How could I find out the answer to your question?

Comment: I can't say for iceweasel, since I don't know how it is distributed, but for Firefox the installation software has localized versions, as shown on this page: [Download Firefox in your language](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/). Your default might depend on you locale or OS. If you don't know the locale for your installation, enter "about:healthreport" in the URL bar, click on "Raw Data", then click on one of the items on the right. Then search for locale and you will see a line like **"locale": "en-US"**.

Comment: See my answer to this question (which is a possible duplicate of yours): https://superuser.com/questions/1215064/change-firefox-default-encoding-for-text-files/1247739#1247739

Answer (score 0):

In `about:config`, set `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` to `true`.

However, this only works for local files (`file:///` URLs).

(shamelessly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49686975/111036))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure this. If the encoding was a function of user-side configuration, people would create content dependent on their own settings, and then the content would not show up correctly for other readers.

For `file:` URLs, Firefox autodetects UTF-8 these days. (The older answer was correct when it was posted, though.)